# Polling a email using async / await

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've created a create a console app that would:

1. Call a method to check an email account (I've done this step)
2. Convert the attachment to pdf (I've done this step)
3. Then once the conversion is complete wait 30 seconds
4. Repeat the previous 3 steps continuously

I've done Step 1 and 2 int the ProcessMailMessages() method. 
The following code works but I want to know if I am on the right track or is there a better way to poll a email client?

```
    private static int secondsToWait = 30 * 1000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool run = true;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                Task theTask = ProcessEmailTaskAsync();
                theTask.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("<p>Error in Client</p> <p>Exception</p> <p>" + e.Message + "</p><p>" + e.StackTrace + "</p> ");
            }
            GC.Collect();

        } while (run);

    }

    static async Task ProcessEmailTaskAsync()
    {
        var result = await EmailTaskAsync();
    }

    static async Task<int> EmailTaskAsync()
    {
        await ProcessMailMessages();
        await Task.Delay(secondsToWait);
        return 1;
    }

    static async Task ProcessMailMessages()
    {
        ...............................................................................
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `CG.Collect();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do smth. like that (I added CancellationToken in case you would want to be able to cancel email parsing while it's in progress):

```
private static TimeSpan timeToWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

//somewhere in your code:
_cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationToken token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessEmailsAndWaitAsync(token).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("<p>Error in Client</p> <p>Exception</p> <p>" + e.Message + "</p><p>" + e.StackTrace + "</p> ");
        }
    } while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);
}

private static async Task ProcessEmailsAndWaitAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    await ProcessMailMessages(token);
    await Task.Delay(timeToWait, token);
}

private static async Task ProcessMailMessages(CancellationToken token)
{
    //...............................................................................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Calling `GC.Collect()` shouldn't be necessary except in very specific circumstances. Don't do it if you don't have a very good reason.
2. Why are do you have unused local variable in `ProcessEmailTaskAsync()`? It's not useful for anything. What's more, what is the whole point of the method? You can `Wait()` on `Task<int>` too.
3. It's not clear what does the `int` returned from `EmailTaskAsync()` mean. If it's supposed to represent status, an `enum` would be much better. If you do need to use `int` for some reason, you really should document what each value means. And in your case, you always return the same value and it doesn't seem to be used anywhere, so you should just change the return type to `Task` and don't return anything.
4. Using `async`-`await` won't give you any benefit in your case. Basically, there are two reasons for using `async`-`await`:

   1. It can use smaller number of threads, improving efficiency.
   2. It can avoid blocking the UI thread, improving responsiveness.

   Neither of those reasons is relevant in your case (you don't have a UI thread and using `async`-`await` this way will use more threads, not less, because of the `Wait()`), so you should consider whether using `async`-`await` will give you any benefit at all.

Comment: Hi Svick,
Thanks for the constructive feedback, Are you able to provide an alternative implementation?

Comment: Why? Are any of my suggestions unclear?

Answer (score -2):

I believe you could use a much more elegant solution using the ContineWith method on the Task object

Here is some basic pseudo code...

```
function RecursiveEmailPollRoutine()
{
    var PollEmailTask = new Task(() => {
                                       //Poll the email
                                       //Pause for your delay
                                   }).ContinueWith(()=> {
                                                            //check your cancel var
                                                            //and cancel if need be
                                                            //otherwise recursively 
                                                            //call this function
                                                        }).Start();
)
```

This hasn't been tested but you get the gist.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't link to your blog in every (or any) answer. Linking to a specific blog post that's relevant to the question is fine as long as you summarize the content of the post in your answer, but just linking to your blog without any indication of how it's relevant to the question is against the rules.

Comment: Are you seriously saying this code is more readable than using `async`-`await`? The whole point of that is to *avoid* code like this. Besides, your code won't work, because you can't `Start()` the `Task` returned from `ContinueWith()`. On the other hand, you have to `Start()` the `Task` if you create it directly using an constructor.